# preventing playing video files outside the app/website

Tags: javascript, python, ffmpeg, video-streaming, mp4

i feel the down votes are coming ! but im desperate so here it goes

i have bunch of videos that i want my users to be able to play them only trough my mobile app or website(not sure about the platform) ... even when they're downloaded on the client side

i've never worked with video files before but i have lots of coding expense and know multiple languages (js , php , python , node , .... )

but i done know where to begin , im not looking for code ... just someone with experience in this area to point me to the right direction and maybe give me some links to read about the subject and what technologies i need to get familiar with

i tried to search around but most results are about html5 player or desktop video players

i was thinking maybe i can encode mp4 files so they wouldn't play with available players and then create a custom video player to decode and show them ?

any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: If it was possible and unbreachable, everyone would do it (like big companies, Netflix, YouTube). If I can see your videos, I can just use an external app to record my screen (and therefore the videos) even if you have the best file protection for them. You should probably just watermark videos so they can't be widely used legally.

Comment: You can add DRM to your videos or even encrypt them, but no protection can withstand a screen recorder if the end user is desperate.